# Low Budget Sound Design (Animal Sounds)

Tags: animals, low-budget, philosophy

What to do when you're working on a low-budget game for children with lots of animals, and you can't source anything pre recorded that's any good?

Specifically sounds for giraffes, rats, and pandas. I want sounds that are at least somewhat representative of the animal... ie. a roar for a lion, an elephant trumpeting.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, maybe not the rat, just panda and giraffe

Comment: add Turtle to the list?


Answer (score 1):

Portable recorder + the zoo - if you go in the early afternoon on a weekday when there are less people and talk to the staff about what you're doing, some times they'll be really cool and let you go to the more secluded sections to record. You can also ask what the feeding times are, and they're usually happy to say. Animals tend to be more vocal during feeding time.

Answer (score 0):

giraffes rarely make any sound, i don't think there are libraries with giraffe vocalisations.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding all of them via a lot more searching. As for the giraffe, apparently they make noise that is too low for human hearing. However, if you get a baby and it's a bit scared, wallah we have something! A bit of RX and editing made it work for my project. In case you wanna see... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7iuOZVJhs0

Answer (score 0):

we have a lot of sounds on our [online library](http://download.prosoundeffects.com), including our 'rare animals' library.

Giraffes do snort a bit.

Pandas make sounds too, but they're not as cute as one would assume.
here's a blog post about panda sounds...
http://www.prosoundeffects.com/blog/2012/09/giant-panda-cub-call-sound-of-the-day

Comment: Ahh neat! Seems like a really cool library! (I'm still rather new to sound design... mostly did composing)


Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for real representation of the animal, but if you are struggling to source you could maybe try looking to create sound gestures from animals that are mostly mute.

Eating habits, movements, etc.